# How to show all the browsing letters in contacts list (right hand side of the screen) in Samsung Galaxy I5500 Europa?

Tags: contacts, samsung-galaxy-5

I am using Samsung Galaxy I5500 (aka Europa). But when I browse contacts list not all the letters through A-Z show in the right hand side of the screen. The missing letters are K,L,Q,R,W,X. So, that It become irritating for me find these first lettered contacts.

Do you guyz have any solution to this?

Thanks for your help in advance

it is like this -

```
----------
         A
         B
         C
         .(in place of K,L,Q,R,W,X)
         Y
         Z
----------
```

Comment: My Galaxy S on 2.2 shows all the letters, hmm.  So you actually have contacts that start with those letters?

Comment: Sure I have!!..

Comment: what's your language/locale?  do you have 2.2?

Comment: locale is english(usa). No, it is 2.1update1.It is a strange problem

Answer (score 1):

This was a problem on early Galaxy S roms too, but it got fixed in the later updates. On the I5500 the low display resolution could prevent from ever showing all the letters. My advice would be to check for firmware updates from Kies, or try a custom rom.

Comment: Yea, I have updated to 2.2 and installed Go Launcher software and it solved the problem. Thnx for ur comment

Answer (score 0):

Letters don't show to save space ... but if you slide your finger slowly you will find all the letters showing in the middle of the screen

Comment: No it doesn't show up!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not fond of the revision but it still works.

Here are 2 methods.

1. Gently press the far right side of one of your contacts.  A letter will appear at the top-middle of the screen.  As you scroll up or down the letter change to reflect which section it is focused on.
2. Gently press where the letters used to be visible, then move your finger a little bit to the left.  If you do it just right a circle with a letter in it will appear next to your finger.  It too will change as you scroll up or down.

Both methods are 'twitchy', hit or miss.
Cheers
John

Comment: thanks for answering after 11 years !! ^^